# AutoMapper mapping nested property using linq

Tags: c#, linq, mapping, automapper

I need to map one property of a nested object in the parent.
Let's say I have `users` that have `roles` but roles have have a translation object called `TransRoles`, this last one have the property `Description` which is the one I want.

### DTO classes

`UsersDTO` markup:

```
public partial class UserDTO
{
    public short Id { get; set; }
    /* ... */

    public virtual RolesDTO RolesDTO { get; set; }
}
```

`RolesDTO` markup:

```
public class RolesDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; } // Mapping destination

    /* ... */
}
```

---

### Data access classes

`Users` markup:

```
public partial class User
{
    public short Id { get; set; }
    /* ... */

    public virtual Roles Roles { get; set; }
}
```

`Roles` markup:

```
public class Roles
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TransRoles> TransRoles { get; set; }

    // this class doesn't have the description    
    /* ... */
}
```

`TransRoles` markup:

```
public class TransRoles
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; } // Mapping source

    /* ... */
}
```

I have the following code, but the description I want from `Users.Roles.TransRoles.Description` is not loaded into `UsersDTO.RolesDTO.Description`:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<User, UserDTO>();

// Dependencies
Mapper.CreateMap<Roles, RolesDTO>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Description, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.TransRoles.FirstOrDefault().Description));
```

---

If I manually map the properties it works, but I think it's not the idea if I'm using a library mapper:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<User, UserDTO>();
Mapper.CreateMap<Roles, RolesDTO>();

// Manually mapping
UserDTO UserDTO = Mapper.Map<UserDTO>(User);
UserDTO.RolesDTO.Descripcion = User.Roles.TransRoles.FirstOrDefault().Description;
```

Comment: Why do you call Mapper.CreateMap<Roles, RolesDTO>() twice? Leave only the second one, that might be the source of the problem. Also don't forget to check src.TransRoles.FirstOrDefault() for null

Comment: Oh sorry, that was an error, `Mapper.CreateMap<Roles, RolesDTO>()` is called only once, *updating question*. And yes, already checked TransRoles.FirstOrDefault(), and it's with data.

Comment: Is your mapping code even called? Can you verify adding .AfterMap with a breakpoint inside of empty function?

Comment: Yes, if I map the properties manually, it all works as expected. I'm gonna update the question.

Comment: By mapping code I meant the rules you defined in your Mapper.CreateMap<Roles, RolesDTO>(). It feels like you might be missing something or there already is a mapping for this pair. You will have to add  .AfterMap(AfterMapFunction) after your .ForMember(dest => dest.Description...) code and verify, that execution is coming into this function. That will point out if the problem is really in mapping function, or in registration of this mapping.

Comment: @GertArnold Sorry, markup fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to find all the internal references of the main object, in my example, `RolesDTO` had more that one child. Besides, I'm currently using Oracle 11 along with EF 6.0 and this version does not support `APPLY` on the queries, so includes where not working the way they supposed to.

### TLDR

Always use `Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();` when mapping objects so you don't miss a thing and if you´re using Oracle 11 with EF 6.0, be careful.